# Summation of a finite series of unit fractions

Tags: number-theory

Let's say I have a series of unit fractions, $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}$, and we know that $a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n} = g$.

Is there a general method or formula to find the outcome of $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}$ simply as an expression of $g$ and $n$?

For example, we know that $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x+y}{xy}$, but is there a more general formula for the summation of a series of $n$ unit fractions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The more general formula for $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x+y}{xy}$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{a_k}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n}{a_k}}}{a_1a_2...a_n}$$
The problem after this here is that you can't access the fact that $a_1+a_2+...+a_n=g$ since you have no common factors in your numerator.